# Is Iron Man stronger than the Hulk?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when Hulk initially uses the new Infinity Gauntlet, it takes a tremendous effort from him (in addition to almost burning his entire arm), in order to snap his fingers and restore the world as we knew it. Yet at the end of the movie, when Iron Man uses the Gauntlet, it seems very easy for him to snap his fingers.

How was Tony able to wield the stones with such ease when Hulk was clearly struggling with it?

Comment: IIRC, it looked like Tony's suit helped manage the radiation/energy from the gauntlet, whereas Hulk just put it on his bare arm. Perhaps that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, Hulk is clearly the stronger of the two.

You have to keep in mind what is actually being accomplished at the time each of them snaps their fingers.

Hulk is bringing back everyone and everything that Thanos destroyed - i.e. 50% of all life in the universe.  He's also trying to force the Stones to bring back Natasha, which they cannot do.

Tony is using the Stones to destroy Thanos and his army.

One is a much bigger task than the other - and although it clearly hurts Hulk, it does

> kill Tony.

Comment: I didn't see any evidence in the movies that the stones require more strength to use if being used for a "bigger" task.

Comment: @GendoIkari ... the relatively trivial activities such as blowing up Thor's ship, or transporting them across half the galaxy, or bringing back Vision and the mind-stone seem to take little effort. It completely seems like the size of the task relates to the strength or effort required.

Comment: I didn't notice Thanos needing to use any effort in Infinity War to do the snap. The only times he struggled to snap was when other people were physically restraining his hand from doing so; both when just trying to use the stones in earlier battles, and when trying to snap for the final snap.

Comment: From what I noticed, all of the strain put on Hulk was related to the act of putting on the glove / wielding the stones. They even specifically mention in dialog that the stones give off immense energy that make it dangerous to the holder. It didn't seem like the act of snapping was what was difficult for him; it was just wielding the stones at all.

Comment: @GendoIkari if I'm not mistaken, post snap we see both the gauntlet itself and the entire (visible) left hand side of Thanos is damaged.  https://images.app.goo.gl/DcvwVjfFxJa7iBHz6

Comment: Its an interesting theory to claim that the size of the task affects the difficulty level of using the gauntlet, but I don't see any evidence from the films that actually suggests this. Its pure speculation based on assumptions.

Comment: @sanpaco the parameters of what make it difficult are not clear sure - but the snap and reverse-snap use all the stones *and* affect a scope of the entire universe, and result in damage to the gauntlet as well as Thanos and Hulk.  We don't see this when other smaller scoped actions happen.  I'd say that more than pure speculation.

Comment: I believe it's the suit taking the initial load of taking on the stones. The suit is not able to handle the effects of the snap. If Tony simply wore the gauntlet without the suit I don't think he would have survived. Like others are stating that hulk struggled soon as he wore it, not just as he is about to snap.

Comment: @MovieMe Tony didn't survive though? Or do you mean he would have died just from putting the gauntlet on, as opposed to after snapping while wielding the stones?

Comment: @Dave, yes, died by just putting on the Gauntlet if he did it with his bear hands.

Comment: Personal theory here, but it's also possible Tony didn't *link* the stones together until the very last moment. It does appear that once the glove is slotted with the stones *and* properly channels all their powers, it's putting out the energy - it's what Hulk seemed to experience. However, simply having the stones near each other isn't enough to produce the same energy. So, if Tony knew he only has one shot at this, it seems like a good idea to only link them together the moment he snaps, so he doesn't get fried before having the opportunity to.

Answer (score 5):

Hulk is stronger. In recent fights hulk beat the crap out of Iron Man unless Iron Man was using his Hulk Buster Suit and even then Tony could only hope to calm the Hulk down, he never had a chance of actually beating him

I also totally agree with the other answers but you also have to remember that was Tony's final move. Hulk struggled but he was also fighting to control the gauntlet and to survive using it. He got time to brace himself for the toll of using the gauntlet. Tony knew what was going to happen when he snapped his fingers and he put every last bit of himself into snapping them

Answer (score 2):

No, in my opinion if you're referring to **strength** of both characters then clearly **Ironman** wasn't stronger than **Hulk**.

Why so? As in the story of endgame, it was mentioned that Hulk was created due to gamma radiation *(ofcourse serums was important part)* and gauntlet would release gamma radiation upon use meaning he might be able to use it with caution and still end up burning his hand.

And clearly in the case of Ironman, he was simply human with extra strength from suit. He weild infinity stones temporary through this suit's nano-fiber technology to hold it for small instance of time although ends up giving his life in such supreme act of snapping fingers.

So if may be Ironman use power from his suit to snap his fingers and if we refer to **@Dave's answer**, restoring "rest of half the universe" takes more strength compared to vanishing "Thanos and his army" & that's why Hulk *struggled* and for Ironman it was *piece of cake*.